# Can I switch off scenery elements on a 3D model?

Tags: unity, assets, game-component

I am using a 3D asset that has flat scenery elements (3D island with 2D bushes). <sup>[1]</sup> Having encountered a number of problems with this scenery <sup>[2]</sup> I want to deactive it (not visible, not collidable, keep the island itself). Is this possible?

[image: 3D island underfoot, 3D rock to left, flat bushes in front]

---

[1]: The asset set in question is http://u3d.as/content/dexsoft-games/platformer-2/3Uo - the problematic objects are things like `AmbientOcclusion/platform2_floating_*.fbx` which (I can see visually) include bits like `plant_9.fbx` which are the misbehaving elements.

[2]: The bushes are collidable making it difficult to move around on the island. Specifically you can walk through them in one direction but not the other. On the suggestion of the creator, we unchecked "Generate colliders" on the island model, but doing that means the whole island has no collider and you fall through it! In addition, the alpha levels on the bushes stopped working, and they appear as rectangular elements (alpha values have been lost, replaced by gray/white) - I must've messed up the alpha value setting but can't figure out how to turn it back on. (If comments reveal these issues are fixable I'll expand them into separate questions.)

Comment: @KellyThomas I think I am using the *wrong* definition of billboard! I've fixed up the question with your suggestions and 1000 words